# Splitting AJAX POST variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have written a script to post `AJAX` variables whenever a `checkbox` is clicked. When multiple `checkboxes` are selected the variables are stored in an array and seperated by a `pipe`. I need each variable to be passed separately into my `php` function so I can run separate queries.

My JavaScript

```
$(document).on("change", ".tbl_list", function () {
    var tbls = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
        tbls.push($(this).val());
    });
    var tbl = tbls.join('|');
    var db = window.sessionStorage.getItem("db");
    alert(db);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax2.php",
        data: {
            tbl: tbl,
            db: db
        },
        success: function (html) {
            console.log(html);
            $("#tblField").html(html).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Output when multiple tables are selected

```
tbl:db|event
```

My PHP function

```
function tblProperties() {
    if (isset ( $_POST ['tbl'] )) {
        $tbl = $_POST ['tbl'];
        $db = $_POST ['db'];
        $link = mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '', $db );
        $qry = "DESCRIBE $tbl";
        $result = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
```

I know I would need to store these variables somehow and then do a `for each` to generate separate queries but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can't you `explode('|', $tbl);` to have an array and then do `foreach($array as $tbl) { }`?

Comment: Why don't you do it in php using `explode`

Comment: How about exploding the variable tbl in PHP with http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
function tblProperties() {
    if (isset ( $_POST ['tbl'] )) {
        $db = $_POST ['db'];
        $tables = explode('|', $_POST ['tbl']); // explode your variable
        $link = mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '', $db );

        foreach($tables as $table) // foreach through it
        {
            $result = mysqli_query ( $link, "DESCRIBE $table" ); // do your query
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                // your code here 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response. I have a question further down my function I had this code `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {` This was what was populating my tables, how would I amend this as currently I get no results while using `$results`.

Comment: `$results` as now an array. Therefore, use `foreach($results as $result) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { } }`

Comment: You could do your `while()` loop inside the first `foreach()` now I'm thinking about it. I'll edit my answer to make it cleaner

Comment: Yes thanks very much for that Edit the previous code made the new table generate data outside of the table row. Now its working perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
function tblProperties() {
    if (isset ( $_POST ['tbl'] )) {
        $tbl = $_POST ['tbl'];
        $db = $_POST ['db'];
        $link = mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '', $db );
     $tblarr =  explode('|', $tbl);
     for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($tblarr); $i++)
    {
         $qry = "DESCRIBE $tblarr[$i]";
        $result[] = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
     }
```

Comment: Why using `for()` instead of `foreach()`? Also, don't use `sizeof()` but `count()` instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php#85892